# Javascript collision ddetection

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I have a hero which moves in the direction of click. in below code, when I pass runH(10,0), as per the code it should move to right and should stop when collision detected, and i works perfectly.
BUT
ISSUE : it stops few pixels before the block ( It does not stick to colliding block ).

```
function runH(x, y) {
    clearInterval(interV);
    inmotion = true;
    interV = setInterval(function () {
        var HeroP = $("#BTB_Hero").position();
        var HeroW = $("#BTB_Hero").width();
        var HeroH = $("#BTB_Hero").height();
        var HeroX = HeroP.left + x;
        var HeroY = HeroP.top + y;
        
        // Check for collisions with blocks
        let collision = false;
       
        for (let i = 0; i < blocksA.length; i++){
         var block = $(blocksA[i]);
         var blockP = block.position();
         var blockX = blockP.left;
         var blockY = blockP.top;
         var blockW = $(blocksA[i]).width();
         var blockH = $(blocksA[i]).height();
         
         if ( HeroX + HeroW >= blockX && HeroX <= blockX + blockW && HeroY + HeroH >= blockY && HeroY <= blockY + blockH) {
             collision = true;
            
             
             break;  //Stop checking for collisions on the first collision detected
         }
     }
     if (collision) {
      clearInterval(interV); // Stop movement on collision
      inmotion = false;
  } else {
      $("#BTB_Hero").css({ "top": HeroY + "px", "left": HeroX + "px" });
  }
        // Check for level change condition
        checkLevelChange(HeroX,HeroY);
    }, 1);
}
```

I tried many thing

1. I decreased the x and y values to 1 , but then speed of hero block decreases to next level and for mobile devices it feels in slowmotion.
2. I tried decreasing the interval (setTimeInterval ) to 1/10000 but it does not work , speed is still slow.
3. Finally i tried to get the width and position of colliding block and adjust the hero to that position after collision.

Expectation :
1.to increase hero speed by keeping x or y as 1
2. to steek to block when collision detects when i keep x and y 10

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you are checking the position of the hero *before* moving them rather than after, resulting in them stopping just before the block.

e.g. If the Hero is at (2, 5) and the block is at (3, 6) at timestep 1, then on timestep 2 the interval function will check the hero's *potential* location at (3, 6) and detect a collision, but the code to move the hero there (`$("#BTB_Hero").css({ "top": HeroY + "px", "left": HeroX + "px" });`) will not be executed and they will remain at (2, 5).

Also just an FYI: Running an interval with delay=1 will almost certainly not actually run every 1ms (the actual delay will depend on the browser and the strength of the hardware) and is most likely unnecessary, you will probably be better off using a delay of at least 10ms.

Comment: Thanks You for Your response, My whole game is complete but due to the speed , I am not able to publish it, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "publish". If your initial question has been answered please accept the answer.

Comment: thanks , here Publish means putting on google play store, but I resolved the issue by modifying in other part of the code,

Comment: @shaileshSingh I believe that standard framerates for animations are between 20 and 60 frames per second. 20 is the minimum framerate required for an animation to not appear as a sequence of still images; 60 approaches the maximum "smoothness" that can be detected by the human eye. So, there is no point in making your framerate >60 fps. 20 fps corresponds to a 50 ms delay between frames; 60 fps is a 16 ms delay per frame.